# RSS for Facebook inbox messages

Tags: facebook, rss

How can I get the RSS feed for my Facebook inbox messages?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this is not possible as RSS feeds are for broadcasting information to many users, while Facebook messages are more similar to your everyday mail client with encryption.

Comment: Pocket provides private RSS.

Comment: @user What is Pocket?

Comment: http://getpocket.com/